# How to pass parameter into jquery on button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Not sure how to pass a parameter from a button click event into my jquery script. Im trying to pass it data from the model so I can use that in my ajax data parameter.

```
<button id="button" value="Delete">Delete</button>
```

JQuery/Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("StudentIndex", "JPApplications")',
            data: param = "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });        

    function successFunc(data, status) {
            alert(data);
        }

    function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the source of data you want to pass ?

Comment: I want to pass the ID of a record

Comment: Try binding the parameter to a variable

Comment: so that id is bind to some html element...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. you can either put your Id of record as a attribute od button. e.g

```
<button id="button" data-id="YOUR ID" value="Delete">Delete</button>
```

in your click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("StudentIndex", "JPApplications")',
        data: param = id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });        

function successFunc(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!! Finally was able to pass my data

Comment: @Bkwiat Can you please mark it as a answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value from onClick event

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var value = e.target.value;
});
```